# How to get correct date and month on node.js and Cloud Functions for Firebase?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am using plain javascript on a node server used on Cloud Functions for Firebase.
json name is : trial.json

```
[{
    "date": "0822",
    "message": "Have a nice day on 0822"
 },
 {
    "date": "0823",
    "message": "Have a nice day on 0823"
 },
 {
    "date": "0824",
    "message": "Have a nice day on 0824"
 },
 {
    "date": "0825",
    "message": "Have a nice day on 0825"
 },
 {
    "date": "0826",
    "message": "Have a nice day on 0826"
 },
 {
    "date": "0827",
    "message": "Have a nice day on 0827"
 },
 {
    "date": "0828",
    "message": "Have a nice day on 0828"
 },
 {
    "date": "0829",
    "message": "Have a nice day on 0829"
 },
 {
    "date": "0830",
    "message": "Have a nice day on 0830"
 },
 {
    "date": "0831",
    "message": "Have a nice day on 0831"
 }]
```

the index.js is

```
var fs = require("fs");
var contents = fs.readFileSync("trial.json");
var jsonContent = JSON.parse(contents);
console.log("Content", jsonContent)
var today = month + date;
var currentDate;
var selectedCeleb = 0;

for (var index = 0; index < jsonContent.length; ++index) {
  var curr = jsonContent[index];
  if(curr.date == today){
      currentDate = curr;
      break;
  }
}
console.log("message : " + currentDate.message)
// Request Response Pair
exports.myApp = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const app = new App({ request, response });
  console.log('Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

function getDayMessage() {
  return currentDate.message;
}

function userMessage (app) {
  let dayMsg = getDayMessage();
  if (app.hasSurfaceCapability(app.SurfaceCapabilities.SCREEN_OUTPUT)) {
      app.ask(app.buildRichResponse()
        .addSimpleResponsedayMsg))
    } else {
        app.ask(dayMsg, NO_INPUTS);    
    }
 }

  let actionMap = new Map();
  actionMap.set(USER_INTERESTED, userMessage);
  app.handleRequest(actionMap);
});
```

The value returned for month + day on my local is 0829
while on the server is 0827.

Please help to identify if it would be settings issue or code issue so that I can update the code to get right values.

Answer (score 2):

Your local machine is probably in a different timezone than the servers running Cloud Functions.  When you use getMonth() and getDate() on a [Date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/date-object-javascript) object, they will return those values in **your local time**, which could be a different date than other timezones around the world.

[getTimezoneOffset()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/gettimezoneoffset-method-date-javascript) will give you the number of minutes your timezone is offset from UTC:

```
new Date().getTimezoneOffset()
```

I live in California in Pacific Standard Time, so on my local machine that returns 420.

Cloud Functions servers are set to UTC, so that function returns 0.

What does return for your machine?  Probably some value that puts you in a different date for most of the day, compared to Cloud Functions servers.  The "correct" date is dependent on your timezone.  If you want a specific timezone, you'll have to do some math with the Date object to get the values you're looking for.

Comment: How is the **2 day** difference explained?

Comment: Are you sure the clock on your machine is set correctly?  The value of toUTCString() for Date objects on my machine match those of Cloud Functions, which means they are in sync.

Comment: I'm not the OP but I ran his code and got **0829**. Are you getting **0827**?!

Comment: @DougStevenson Clock on which machine? Local seems to correct do we need to set anything on Firebase Cloud Functions? And by any means can I login to the machine(the server) and check these values?

Comment: As far as I can tell, Cloud Functions is correct.  It would be catastrophic if it was not.  Google puts a lot of effort into making sure server dates are correct.

Comment: It was working fine on 23rd of August and two things changed after that: 1) Pushed to latest node version and 2) Changed the server plan so not sure what is causing the issue.

Comment: How exactly are you triggering the function?  Do you have minimal, complete function code that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @DougStevenson Updated the question with minimal example. The json matches the current date and should return specific message that is 0829 and not 0827

Comment: @DougStevenson Seems the issue was with upgrading the cloud functions to Blaze 'Play as you go' model. I moved back to Spark 'Free tier' and it resulted correctly.

Comment: Your function code doesn't look like a complete function.  Where's your module export?  What kind of function is it?  Database trigger?  HTTP?  Something else?  How are you triggering it?

Comment: My local `getTimezoneOffset` is -60 (The Netherlands). The `getTimezoneOffset` of an `europe-west1` function, which is supposed to be based in Belgium, is 0. Also, Timestamps are saved in Firestore as UTC + 1 but transforming them, in the function, into Dates with `toDate()` subtracts 2 hours. I'm triggering the callable function from my Firebase Web App. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

DougStevenson:
Not sure what explanation would be but just downgrading to Spark it works correctly. So whatever this blaze (Pay as you go) is doing is causing the issue. I would certainly keep it open and take up later.

[image]

Comment: My project is on Blaze and I can't reproduce.  Please contact Firebase support.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: @DougStevenson so for you everytime it returns 0829?

Comment: Yes, when I run the code *inside an HTTP function, triggered on demand by an HTTP request*.

Comment: I changed back to blaze and tried, this time it worked fine, would there be a case where the dates are cached or something?

Comment: @DougStevenson It seems the data is cached and returned if my request query is same. Can you let me no how to stop caching completely?

Comment: Your function code doesn't look like a complete function. Where's your module export? What kind of function is it? Database trigger? HTTP? Something else? How are you triggering it?

Comment: exports.myApp = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const app = new App({ request, response });
  console.log('Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

....

this is my http call, which has methods that look for values in the json and as told it returns yesterday's result even though I query for today.

Comment: I don't see how that bit of code has anything to do with the other code from the question.  Can you edit the question to show how all this fits together?

Comment: @DougStevenson Updated the question, let me know if it is clear, I am trying to post the whole code as this is open to public.

Comment: You're going to have to do the work with dates *inside* the function body.  You can't do it outside the function body, because it will only be executed once and remembered for as long as the instance that hosts it is still running.

Comment: @DougStevenson you mean this piece?
for (var index = 0; index < jsonContent.length; ++index) {
  var curr = jsonContent[index];
  if(curr.date == today){
      currentDate = curr;
      break;
  }
}